# PL/SQL Developer Can't See Results Of Insert Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, plsqldeveloper

As the title says - when I perform an "INSERT" statement, I can't see the results unless I re-open PL/SQL Developer.

To make things a bit more clear:
After I perform this statement on the empty table "worker_temp" -

```
insert into worker_temp
select * from worker_b
```

I see that 100 records have been inserted:
[image]

But when I try to see the results using this query:

```
select * from worker_temp;
```

I still see an empty table:

[image]


But only after I quit PL/SQL Developer and re-open it, I can see the records that I inserted earlier:

[image]

**Is there a way to see the changes without closing and re-opening PL/SQL Developer?**

**What I've tried so far:**

I've tried to refresh the table using right click on it:

[image]

And I've also tried to refresh the whole tables folder:

[image]

I also tried committing -

```
commit;
```

But I'm not sure what that even is.

Comment: [This is what commit does](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/COMMIT.html). Are your insert and select in separate database sessions? e.g separate windows which don't have a shared connection? (Also: PL/SQL is a language. Presumably you're referring to the PL/SQL Developer application?)

Comment: Did you query to see the results in the same PL/SQL Developer window as the one where you inserted the data? The default setting in PL/SQL Developer is **multi-session** (see Configure > Preferences > Connection > Session mode), which means each window you have open is logged into the database in a separate session. A session can't see another session's changes until it commits. Committing means saving the changes, a little bit like saving a Word document. PL/SQL Developer also has a button for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tool agnostic way:

```
begin
insert into worker_temp
select * from worker_b;
commit;
end;
```

Judging by all the screenshots you are likely getting separate database sessions in 'each' tab you are using - which is a good thing.  You have to issue the commit on the same session that performed the insert.  Another way of understanding this:

```
begin
  insert into worker_temp select * from worker_b;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Rows inserted but not committed ' || SQL%ROWCOUNT);
  -- 'undo' the insert by rolling back the insert instead of commit.
  rollback;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you! The took agnostic way worked. Can you explain? (I don't even understand what "tools agnostic" means).

Comment: @Elyasaf755 - It looks like you are using TOAD or some other feature rich tool to connect to your Oracle database.  So that tool has a lot of power but can also make it harder to learn in some ways.  A simple command line client like sqlplus or sqlcl will help make it clear what the 'client' is expected to communicate verse what the 'database server' is.  Oracle documentation on the "COMMIT;" statement may be a good place to start:  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_4011.htm#SQLRF01110

Comment: @Elyasaf755 The reason this worked is because of the `commit;` It doesn't need the `begin` or `end` keywords to work, as long as you execute both parts (the `insert` and the `commit`). I see this answered your question in terms of getting the row inserted, however I have posted an answer that explains what is going on in PL/SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

The default setting in PL/SQL Developer is **Multi session**:

[image: PL/SQL Developer Connections preference settings screen]

This means that each editor window you have open is logged into the database in a separate session. A session can't see another session's changes until it commits. This is rather like saving a shared Excel spreadsheet on a network drive. Nobody can see your changes until you have finished making them, which you'll appreciate is an important feature in a multi-user database.

In PL/SQL Developer, the **Multi session** default setting means that you can start a long-running query in one SQL window, and then get on with something else in another without being blocked and having to wait for it. With this setting, you'll need to commit your changes before any other editor window can see them. There are Commit and Rollback icons in the toolbar, or you can type `commit;` and execute it.

However, I always set mine to **Dual session**, meaning all windows are part of the same session, even if it means I sometimes have to wait for something. I find this simplifies things considerably, and also I can make changes across multiple windows without needing to commit, which can be helpful when working with global temporary tables or `alter session` commands.

Read more in [this setup guide](https://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/plsqldeveloper-setup-1.html).